# Ubuntu Font different in Chromium and Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, ubuntu, fonts, chromium

Why does the Ubuntu Font (http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Ubuntu) shows differently in Chromium and Google Chrome?

[image: Ubuntu Font different in Chromium and Google Chrome]
*(Google Chrome on the right)*

In Chromium every `font-weight` looks right but in Google Chrome the **Light**, **Normal** and **Medium** are all the same.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Chromium 29.0.1547.65
- Google Chrome 30.0.1599.101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most plausible explanation is that your computer has Ubuntu (well, a font *named* Ubuntu) installed, but not with all the typefaces that Google distributes.

The reason is that I was able to construct a similar situation on my computer (Win 7). Initially, both Chrome and Firefox (I used it for comparison, because I don’t have Chromium) displayed the Google page OK. I had Ubuntu, as downloaded from Google pages, with all the typefaces there, as a normal installed font. I then removed Ubuntu Light and Medium (but not their italic versions), and Windows refused to do this (saying the fonts are in use) until I closed Chrome (but having the page open in Firefox wasn’t a problem). When restarted, Chrome now showed both Light 300 and Light 300 Italic as light italic!

So it seems that Chrome decides that when a font *family* called Ubuntu exists in the system, it does not fetch font files from the Google server but uses the locally installed font. This would be OK, but Chrome fails to notice that the font does not have all the typefaces needed, so it gets confused and seems to use other typefaces in their stead.

When I completely removed Ubuntu from my system, Chrome again shows the page OK.

I’m not 100% sure of this analysis, and I’m not sure at all of the implications. Presumably, the problem only appears for users that have the font installed in their system. And probably the problem can be avoided if you do not use fonts as hosted by Google but download them, create the usual `@font-face` kit, and do not include any `local(...)` part in your `src` declarations. This would mean some degradation of performace in the (probably rare) cases where the font exists as installed.

Comment: I've download the Ubuntu font from [http://font.ubuntu.com](http://font.ubuntu.com)  and it seams that I've all the Light, Normal, Medium and Bold fonts installed on my system.
I follow your advice and removed `local(..)` form the source in my css [https://gist.github.com/7056371](https://gist.github.com/7056371) and right now I just can't tell the difference betwwen Normal (400) and Medium (500)

Comment: I was importing this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700:latin">`. After removing it from the `<head>` the previous gists worked like a charm. Answer accepted!

Comment: I believe this is related to an upstream Chromium bug tracked in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143